# Find document by field in sub-array and return another field in same sub-array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, nested

I have a collection called `products`, which has documents containing several fields, along with a `variants` sub-array.

The `variants` sub-arrays have several fields, including `sku` and `id`.

**I know the `id` value, and I need to use it to get the `sku` value.**

The simplified collection looks like this:

```
[
    "_id"      => "whatever_id_1",
    "field_2"  => "some value 1",
    "variants" => 
        [
            "id"  => "some_id_123"
            "sku" => "SKU-1"
        ],
        [
            "id"  => "some_id_124"
            "sku" => "SKU-2"
        ],
        [
            "id"  => "some_id_125"
            "sku" => "SKU-3"
        ]
],
[
    "_id"      => "whatever_id_2",
    "field_2"  => "some value 2",
    "variants" => 
        [
            "id"  => "some_id_126"
            "sku" => "SKU-4"
        ],
        [
            "id"  => "some_id_127"
            "sku" => "SKU-5"
        ],
        [
            "id"  => "some_id_128"
            "sku" => "SKU-6"
        ]
],
[
    "_id"      => "whatever_id_3",
    "field_2"  => "some value 3",
    "variants" => 
        [
            "id"  => "some_id_129"
            "sku" => "SKU-7"
        ],
        [
            "id"  => "some_id_130"
            "sku" => "SKU-8"
        ],
        [
            "id"  => "some_id_131"
            "sku" => "SKU-9"
        ]
]
```

I am retrieving the correct document with

```
// Set item_id
$item_id = 'some_id_127';
// Build 'find product with inventory item id' query
$find_product_with_id_query = [ 'variants' => ['$elemMatch' => ['id' => $item_id] ] ];
// Get the product document to process 
$inventory_update_product = $client_products_collection->findOne($find_product_with_id_query);
```

This properly returns the parent document with `"_id" => "whatever_id_2"`.

Now, I know I can iterate over that results (eg. `$inventory_update_product['variants'`), and find the `sku` value that way.

**QUESTIONS**
1. But is there some way to get the `sku` value with MongoDB?
2. Is there any benefit to using MongoDB for this last step, or is it more efficient to just use PHP for loop to find the `sku`?

Comment: `$item_id = some_id_127';` missing a quote there, to answer you question you can use projection and an aggregate query and probably a bit of JS.  I'd have to look it up but it's possible.  So the answer is -- 1. Yes, 2. Benchmark it.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/  if you look a project, basically it creates a temporary document that you can edit the schema to add a new field (your total).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, actually. You can use projection:

```
// Set item_id
$item_id = 'some_id_127';

// Build 'find product with inventory item id' query
$find_product_with_id_query = [ 'variants' => ['$elemMatch' => ['id' => $item_id] ] ];

// Project and limit options
$options = [
    'projection' => [ 'variants.$' => 1 ],
    'limit' => 1
];

// Get the product document to process 
$inventory_update_product = $client_products_collection->find($find_product_with_id_query, $options);
```

This will return a cursor containing the document with the array `variants` with only the element matching the one you searched for.

Exact syntax may vary depending on driver version and whether or not you're using the userland library.